# Create category in sql based on same value

Tags: sql

I need help to create SQL syntax which will create category idd like 1,2,3 on based on same value in column `tovar`. And it should add `idd` if not exist

Table

```
Co         Datum       Jednota    Tovar      Kod      Kusy.   Idd  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predaj     29.4.06.    Tr002.     Kalan.     2123.     10   
Predaj.    28.4.06.    Tr004.     Phal.      2134.      8
Predaj.    28.5.06.    Tr009.     Kalan.     2343.     19
```

Comment: Can you share the result you're trying to get for this sample data?

Comment: Result shoud by in collumn.  Idd.  1,2,1.

Comment: Also, what [tag: rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what it really is . You mean if collumn type  is varchar ,data or something like maria-db?